# How we make window draggable without mouse down in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, window

I have different scenario here I want to make my wpf application drag able with window Style none. If I use following code it works, but I stops the other events on halt. Like I put an custom close and minimize image, this method stop its Mouse_up event. Please help me.

```
private void Canvas_Loaded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     this.MouseDown += delegate 
     {
          DragMove(); 
     };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, try attaching this handler to the `Window` and not the `Canvas`. Secondly, try attaching to the `MouseLeftButtonDown` or `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` events instead. Try this:

```
private void Window_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    DragMove();
}
```

Comment: sorry, it didn't work. still it makes custom Close and Minimise function halted

Comment: You have shown us no evidence of your problem. Please edit your question to show us a *complete, concise working code example* that demonstrates your problem and then we might be able to fix it.